# Why does React setState callback function fail to fire sometimes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an svg button that contains children elements(polygons). The handleMouseLeave function is used to set the state and then utilize its callback to update the children immediatley after. Even though the 'mouseleave' and 'callback' logs both fire in order, the rest of the code inside the callback area does not always fire.

Is there a better or correct way to handle the callback?

```
  handleMouseLeave = (e) => {
    console.log('mouseleave')
    const polygons = [...e.target.children];
    this.setState({
      translate: "translateX(-100%)",
      opacity: 0
    }, () => {
      console.log('callback')
      polygons.forEach(child => {
        child.style.transform = this.state.translate;
        child.style.opacity = this.state.opacity;
      });
    });
  };
```

--

```
render() {
    return(
      <button>
        <HeroButtonSVG
          id="HeroButton"
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        />
        <span>Check out my work<i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </button>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Probably missing `return` keyword, - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the actual issue was derived from the pointer-events on the child SVG's. The issue was not related to React's setState callback function.

I tracked the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4492

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an event binding issue, as class methods are not bound by default.

To solve this, you can add the following to the render function, which will bind the event, through using arrow functions to automatically bind:

```html
<HeroButtonSVG
   id="HeroButton"
   onMouseEnter={e => this.handleMouseEnter(e)}
   onMouseLeave={e => this.handleMouseLeave(e)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not work. I am also unsure how to test this so it makes it that much more difficult.

Comment: OK no worries. Are there any runtime exceptions getting thrown in the method -e.g. anything in chrome dev tools console? Also, might be worth debugging the source file through chrome dev tools if you haven't already.